# Doing RealmSwift with FILO record insertion with 50 records limitation

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have NotificationList Object which show many notification data with tableView.

```
import RealmSwift

class NotificationList: Object {
    dynamic var title = ""
    dynamic var body = ""
    dynamic var createdAt = NSDate()
    let notifications = List<Notification>()
}
```

Everytime I do insert record,I run this function using RealmSwift.

```
func insertNotification(list: NotificationList){
        try! realm.write({ () -> Void in
            realm.add(list)
        })
}
```

But,what I really need a help with was,I want to check all total count of NotificationList Realm object before it insert records anytime the notifications come in.And after i did check total count,I want to **delete** if total count exceeds more than 50**(count<=50)** using **FILO(First In Last Out)** by **createdAt sorting**.

Any help with how to do that realmSwift query every time that I insert new records?I am new to RealmSwift.I can only do CRUD for now because I am beginner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're on the right track. :)

Realm has a very useful feature in the fact that results from queries dynamically update as the underlying data is modified, as such, it's quite trivial to iterate through your existing list of notification lists, and remove the older ones until the count is down to 50 again.

```
func insertNotification(list: NotificationList){
    // Insert the new list object
    try! realm.write { 
        realm.add(list)
    }

    // Iterate through all list objects, and delete the earliest ones
    // until the number of objects is back to 50
    let sortedLists = realm.objects(NotificationList).sorted("createdAt")
    while sortedLists.count > 50 {
        let first = sortedLists.first
        try! realm.write {
            realm.delete(first)
        }    
    }
}
```

Let me know how you go!

Comment: Thanks,it worked.Also below answer worked too.I try to learn the difference thanks.I will use yours instead.

Answer (score 3):

A more concise alternative:

```
func insertNotification(list: NotificationList) {
    // Insert the new list object
    try! realm.write { 
        realm.add(list)
    }

    // Trim the number of objects back down to 50, keeping the newest objects.
    let sortedLists = realm.objects(NotificationList).sorted("createdAt")
    if sortedLists.count > 50 {
        try! realm.write {
            realm.delete(sortedLists.prefix(sortedLists.count - 50))
        }    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to get the count of NotificationList objects, and then need to delete any excess objects if their count is more than or equal to 50, plus one more for the object being inserted. You will need to delete older objects. Here is the implementation that can help you.

```
func insertNotification(list: NotificationList){

  //Check if there are more than 50 notifications lists already we want
  //to delete all items in access of 50 plus one more to accommodate
  //the new  object being inserted.

  let sortedItems = realm.objects(NotificationList).sorted("createdAt")

  while sortedItems.count >= 50 {
    let first = sortedItems.first
    try! realm.write {
      realm.delete(first)
    }
  }


  //Now add the new object
  try! realm.write({ () -> Void in
    realm.add(list)
  })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help,It really worked.But,I will try for above one instead.And I still want to learn your code.Thanks.

Comment: The way the deletion is handled in this answer is incorrect. `Results` live-updates to reflect changes made to the `Realm`. This means that on the first iteration we delete `sortedItems[0]`. This causes `sortedItems` to update to no longer contain the deleted item. On the next iteration, `sortedItems[1]` is deleted. This is the object that was at `sortedItems[2]` on the first iteration. In other words, we're skipping every second object!

Answer (score 0):

**Same Logic in CoreData**

```
let aryCoreData = CoreDataManager.shared.fetch(DataDB.self)
    for i in 0...aryCoreData.count-1 {
        if i > 4 {
            let first = aryCoreData.first!
            CoreDataManager.shared.delete(object: first)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Using 'while' can cause fatal errors so i decided to use for loop with same logic.